# is there a better way to append a QVector for 'zero padding'?

Tags: qt, qvector

I have a QVector (v) of length (n), which has multiple values already in it.  I want to double the length of this QVector and populate the second half with 0s.  Is there a better way to do this than:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    v.append(0);
}
```

It just feels inefficient/inelegant to be calling append in a loop

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Simply double the length by calling `v.resize( 2*v.length() )`. That's all.

### Explanation

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize) says that `QVector<T>::resize()` initializes the new elements with a default-constructed value. When `T` is a numeric type, the default value is 0.